# Setting ImageSrc for each template

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

So I am in a confusing situation right now, I have a ListView with an ItemTemplate that contains an Image element:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" class="main" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("photo1") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In my click event I have the following code:

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var img = ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("Image1") as Image;

  var lbl = ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label;

        string image = img.ImageUrl;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
        {

            if (img.ImageUrl == "defaultcar.jpg")
            {
                img.ImageUrl = "images/defaultcar.jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                img.ImageUrl = "images/" + "44/" + image;
            }
        }
  }
```

So in my DB I have 2 images, one called "defaultcar.jpg" and another called "car.jpg" what I am trying to do is create the correct path for each image, I have debugged everything and it seems the first ItemTemplate is displaying "images/44/defaultcar.jpg" and the second ItemTemplate is displaying "car.jpg", it should be the other way round, "images/44/car.jpg" and "images/defaultcar.jpg"

does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, you can solve it as below:

First create method to return Image url like:

```
protected string GetImageUrl(object imageUrl)
{
   if(imageUrl == null)
     return "";
   if(imageUrl.ToString() == "defaultcar.jpg")
      return = "images/defaultcar.jpg";
   else
     return "images/44/" + imageUrl.ToString();

}
```

Then update .aspx file:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" class="main" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrl(Eval("photo1")) %>' />
```